# xpath: find table cell with same position in different row

Tags: html, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am parsing a webpage that includes a structure like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>Label 1</td>
    <td>Label 2</td>
    <td>Label 3</td>
    <td>Something else</td>
<\tr>
<tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
<\tr>
```

What I need to do is select an item based on it's label, so my thought is if the label is in the 3rd  tag in it's row, I can grab the 3rd  tag in the next row to find the item.  I can't figure out a way to use the position() function in this way, and maybe xpath (1.0) is unable to handle this type of filtering.

My best attempt so far is: `//td[ancestor::tr[1]/preceding-sibling::tr[1]/td[position()]]`.  I was hoping the position() function would grab the position of the `<td>` at the beginning of the xpath, since the rest of the xpath is a filter for that node.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: What library/programming language are you using to execute your XPaths?  I don't think this can be done in pure XPath 1.0, you'd need to store the `position()` from the outer context in a variable and then use that variable inside the predicate, and how you set variables varies from tool to tool.

Comment: I'm using selenium webdriver.

Comment: Which selenium-webdriver language bindings are you using? It is likely easier to make use of various selenium methods rather than a pure xpath solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track -- yes, you can use `position()` along with `count()`.

To select the text `Item 2` given `Label 2`:

```
//td[. = 'Label 2']/../following-sibling::tr/td[position() = count(//td[. = 'Label 2']/preceding-sibling::td)+1]/text()
```

**Explanation:**  Select the **nth** cell where **n** is given by the number of sibling cells that exist before the cell that has the desired label in the previous row.  In effect, use the `count()` function to determine position in the label row and then select the corresponding cell in the next row down by matching against its `position()`.

Comment: The problem is, I need to grab the corresponding item from the neighboring `<tr>` tag.  Like for 'Label 2', return 'Item 2'.

Comment: Ah, that's a bit harder but also doable.  See updated answer above.